# What does the 呢 in "你听什么呢？" mean?

Tags: vocabulary

I know that it means "What are you listening to?" but I'm curious as to what the 呢 is supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

呢 is a final particle. It denotes interrogative form in your example sentence. (it has other usages in other context)

You can just use a question mark e.g. "你在听什么？" (what are you listening ) to mark the sentence as a question

"呢" in "你在听**什么呢**？” asks the question of "**what**" are you listening to

"嗎" in "你在**听**什么**嗎**？” asks the question of "**are**" you **listening** to something

Comment: Thanks! One last question: Is the 在 optional? I've heard people use both with and without 在 and I'm wondering if its existence changes anything.

Comment: @Seankala 在 functions similar to ~ing in English here. 你听什么呢? = you listen to what? ; 你在听什么呢? = you are listening to what?

Comment: @TangHo What's the difference between 你听什么 and 你听什么呢 then?

Comment: @Enrico Brasil  "你听什么?"  sounds blunt ; "你听什么呢?"  ends the speech with a softer tone, plus, it stresses the pronoun '什么', make sure people understand you are asking 'what' is being listened to; Not "are you listen to something?"

Answer (score 1):

Use of 呢 due to presence of interrogative pronoun 什么（similar to 吗 for yes-no questions) quoting e.g. 图解基础汉语语法：

> ＂呢＂可以用在有**疑问代词**＂谁＂、＂怎么＂、＂什么＂、＂哪＂等的疑问句中，＂呢＂出现不出现都不影响疑问的表达，＂呢＂有缓和语气的作用。格式：含疑问代词的句子＋（呢）？A：妈妈，你买了点什么（呢）？B：很多东西，你猜猜。A：这么晚才回来，你到哪儿去了（呢）？B：我去参加同学的生日晚会了。Attention:如果句中有疑问代词：＂吗＂不能出现在句末，只能用＂呢＂。E.g.✓他是谁呢？✗他是谁吗？✓妈妈，你买了点什么呢？✗妈妈，你买了点什么吗？✓这么晚才回来，你到哪儿去了呢？✗这么晚才回来，你到哪儿去了吗？✓你怎么不去呢？✗你怎么不去吗？